# Color field and text value in each selectbox option

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I have dynamically added the option values in selectbox. But for each option I want to show a small color bar + description with respect to color bar. Description would be right to color bar.

What is the way to incorporate color bar + description in each option values of selectbox dynamically?

The following code is adding option values.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) { 
   Options += '<option value="' + item[i] + '">' + item[i] + '</option>';
   }
```

My requirement is to add color bar using small text field of width 1em next to item value .

Answer (score 0):

If this bar is on the background of the text you can use the propriety style inside the option tag and use some math formula to use the i to calculate the colour using rgb codes

```
<option style="background-color: rgb(255,255,i);"> item i </option>
```

Try to find some calculation with i that produces values from 0 to 255 with a good difference between them, the formula depends on the scope of your i of course it can be something like 255 - i x 10, to produce enough contrast between your options

Comment: No i don't want color at background i want the color bar next to value of option. I hope I am able to make myself clear this time.